# Filtering and Counting simultaneously in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm using Entity Frame work and I get the following json from my Get method.

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Coffee",
        "icon": "alarm",
        "staticEvents": [
            
            
            {
                "id": 36,
                "categoryId": 2,
                "time": "2021-12-26T12:22:46.609+10:00",
                "comment": null
            },
            {
                "id": 38,
                "categoryId": 2,
                "time": "2021-05-28T00:00:00+10:00",
                "comment": null
            },
            {
                "id": 40,
                "categoryId": 2,
                "time": "2021-05-28T00:00:00+10:00",
                "comment": null
            },
            {
                "id": 42,
                "categoryId": 2,
                "time": "2021-05-28T00:00:00+10:00",
                "comment": null
            },
            {
                "id": 44,
                "categoryId": 2,
                "time": "2021-05-28T00:00:00+10:00",
                "comment": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Water",
        "icon": "alert",
        "staticEvents": [
            {
                "id": 32,
                "categoryId": 3,
                "time": "2021-05-28T14:33:47.765643+10:00",
                "comment": null
            },
            {
                "id": 37,
                "categoryId": 3,
                "time": "2021-05-20T13:00:58.123+10:00",
                "comment": null
            },
            {
                "id": 39,
                "categoryId": 3,
                "time": "2021-05-28T00:00:00+10:00",
                "comment": null
            },
            {
                "id": 41,
                "categoryId": 3,
                "time": "2021-05-28T00:00:00+10:00",
                "comment": null
            },
            {
                "id": 43,
                "categoryId": 3,
                "time": "2021-05-28T00:00:00+10:00",
                "comment": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And I need something with the following format:

```
[
    {
        "month": June,
        "report": [

            {
                "categoryId": 2,
                "occurrences": 5,
            },

 {
                "categoryId": 3,
                "occurrences": 4,
            }

    }
]
```

I imagine it's something along the lines of GroupBy + Select as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416612/c-sharp-count-ocurrences-in-each-date-using-linq) but I couldn't get the count of occurrences in the sub-list.

EDIT: I'm trying to run the queries step by step and I'm getting errors.

- When I run:

```
 var list = _context.Categories
            .SelectMany(c => c.StaticEvents )
            .GroupBy (staticEvent => new 
            {
                Year = staticEvent.Time.Year,
                Month = staticEvent.Time.Month
            })
            .ToList();

            foreach(StaticEvent i in list) {
                Console.WriteLine(i.CategoryId);
            }
```

I get

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side.
```

So I used:

```
var list = _context.Categories
            .SelectMany(c => c.StaticEvents )
            .AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy (staticEvent => new 
            {
                Year = staticEvent.Time.Year,
                Month = staticEvent.Time.Month
            })
            .ToList();
```

then I'm getting

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Grouping`2[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.Int32,System.Int32],api.Entities.StaticEvent]' to type 'api.Entities.StaticEvent'.
```

Comment: That's json you have. Deserialize it in classes that represent that structure and then select what you need and serialize it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of going about this using Newtonsoft and anonymous types, assuming your json string is stored in a variable called `json`:

```
//Parse into array
var obj = JArray.Parse(json);

//Gather all events
var allEvents = obj.AsEnumerable().Select(t => t["staticEvents"])
    .SelectMany(t => t.Select(t1 => new { categoryId = t1["categoryId"].ToString(), time = DateTime.Parse(t1["time"].ToString()) }));

//Group events by month
var groupedByMonth = allEvents.GroupBy(r => r.time.Month, i => i.categoryId);

//Generate aggregates
var monthAggregates = groupedByMonth.Select(gbm =>
new
{
    month = gbm.Key,
    report =
    gbm.GroupBy(m => m)
    .Select(entry => new
    {
        categoryId = entry.Key, ocurrences = entry.Count()
    })
});

//Display
foreach (var monthAggregate in monthAggregates)
{
    var monthDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, monthAggregate.month, 1);
    Console.WriteLine($"Month: {monthDate.ToString("MMMM")}");
    Console.WriteLine($"report:");
    foreach (var entry in monthAggregate.report)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"category: {entry.categoryId}, ocurrences: {entry.ocurrences}");
    }                
}
```

Output:

```
Month: December
report:
category: 2, ocurrences: 1
Month: May
report:
category: 2, ocurrences: 4
category: 3, ocurrences: 5
```

I am sure there are many things you can do to this code to make it "better". It's just meant to help you get going.

Comment: I've updated my question explaining some errors I encountered while trying to run the suggested queries against Entity Framework. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

An example using only lambdas expressions

```
            var json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\Arquivo.txt");
            var objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RequestObj>>(json);

            var resultObjs = objs
                            .SelectMany(x => x.StaticEvents.Select(y => y.Time))
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Month)
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                Month = x.First().ToString("MMMM"),
                                Index = x.Key
                            }) 
                            .Select(x => new ResultObj
                            {
                                Month = x.Month,
                                Report = objs
                                            .Where(y => y.StaticEvents.Where(z => z.Time.Month == x.Index).Any())
                                            .Select(y => new Report
                                            {
                                                CategoryId = y.Id,
                                                Occurrences = y.StaticEvents.Where(z => z.Time.Month == x.Index).Count()
                                            })
                                            .ToList()
                            })
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: This works really well, but not against EF, I'm getting "Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side."

Comment: I've updated my question explaining some errors I encountered while trying to run the suggested queries against Entity Framework. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Separate your problem into two subproblems:

- Read the Json into a sequence of `Drinks`, each `Drink` with zero or more `StaticEvents`
- Use LINQ to create your output format.

The advantage is, that you can reuse your LINQ code if your input format is in XML, or a CSV-file, or from a database, or maybe from the internet.

I assume you know how to read JSON.

```
class Drink
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Icon {get; set;}   // or maybe an enum?

    public ICollection<StaticEvent> StaticEvents {get; set;}
}

public StaticEvent
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public DateTime Time {get; set;};
    public string Comment {get; set;}
}

public IEnumerable<Drink> ReadJsonDrinks() {...}
```

> **Requirement** Given a sequence of Drinks, each Drink with zero or more StaticEvents, create an output sequence of months, each month having a sequence of `Reports`. Every Report has a CategoryId, and a number of Occurences. Meaning: how many times did a StaticEvent of this CategoryId occur in this month.

We'll use SelectMany to get one sequence of all StaticEvents (of all Drinks). We won't use the Drink anymore.

Once we got the big sequence of all StaticEvents, we make groups of StaticEvents that occurred in the same [Year, Month] combinaation. In other words, the group with Key `June 2021`, has all StaticEvents that occurred in June 2021.

I know you wrote "June", but I think that you don't want to combine june 2020 and june 2021 into one month. If you do want this, leave out the mentions of year in the solution below.

To create the Reports in group `June 2021`, we have to GroupBy again: make groups StaticEvent that have the same CategoryId. We use parameter resultSelector to convert each group into a [CategoryId, numer of static events with this categoryId]

For these two GroupBy I use the overload of GroupBy that has a parameter resultSelector.

So we'll start with the SelectMany to create one big sequence of all StaticEvents of all Drinks.

```
IEnumerable<Drink> drinks = ReadJsonDrinks();

var result = drinks.SelectMany(drink => drink.StaticEvents)
```

Now we make groups of StaticEvents that occurred in the same [year, month] combination:

```
.GroupBy(staticEvent => new
{
    Year = staticEvent.Time.Year,
    Month = staticEvent.Time.Month,
}

// parameter resultSelector, from every [year, month] combination, and all StaticEvents
// that have a Time with this [year, month] create one new:
(yearMonth, staticEventsWithThisYearMonth) => new
{
    ... // TODO: implement
});
```

Now what do we want: per [year month]? We want the year and the month, and a sequence of Reports. So the LINQ above:

```
(yearMonth, staticEventsWithThisYearMonth) => new
{
    Year = yearMonth.Year,
    Month = yearMonth.Month,

    // for the reports: make groups of staticEvents that have the same CategoryId:
    Reports = staticEventsWithThisYearMonth.GroupBy(staticEvent => staticEvent.CategoryId,

    // parameter resultSelector: for every CategoryId, and all staticEvents with this categoryId
    // (that were in this year/month), make one Report:
    (categoryId, staticEventsWithThisCategoryId) => new
    {
        CategoryId = categoryId,

        // for the occurrences: count the number of StaticEvents in this group:
        Occurences = staticEventsWithThisCategoryId.Count(),
    })
    .ToList(),
});
```

Comment: I've updated my question explaining some errors I encountered while trying to run the suggested queries against Entity Framework. Thanks for your time!